# Composer update gives error saying plugin could not be initialized, class not found for every package

Tags: php, composer-php, vagrant

I've loaded up a vagrant box from scratch with an existing codebase that has been running on several machines for quite a while. When running composer update it always gives a similar issue:

```
  - Removing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.1.1)


  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Plugin kylekatarnls/update-helper could not be initialized, class not found: UpdateHelper\ComposerPlugin
```

php -v:

```
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Composer version 1.8.6

I've tried changing versions of vagrant, virtualbox, php, xdebug, composer all to match versions running on other machines. I've tried composer clearcache, composer dump-autoload, various different composer update methods. Have tried deleting vendor folder and doing composer install

Comment: Have you tried removing the content of `vendor` and running `composer install` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks Nico, unfortunately I have. I've updated original question.

Comment: And what happens after removing everything from `vendor`? There should not be the same error message, as there is no package to remove then

Comment: The same issue happens. Should have posted more of the error. It was trying to install it initially, fails after printing about unzipping the package (doesn't actually give an error message) then proceeds to uninstall again afterwards

Comment: "fails after printing about unzipping the package" - I don't get that. Is there really not a single line of information given about that error? Then how do you know that it fails?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a Vagrant box, I removed php7.2-zip from installing and installed ONLY zip.

If I have them both installed, it fails, if I install only php-zip it failed. Not sure if this will help, but might give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

Run `composer update --no-plugins`.